# Como fazer login com Facebook no React Native no novo formato?

Tags: javascript, facebook, login, react-native

Já fiz anteriormente a integração com o Facebook no React Native, e para tal eu alterei algumas linhas de código diretamente na pasta Android da Aplicação. Porém na aplicação que estou fazendo agora senti uma série de diferenças, entre elas a inexistência da pasta Android...

Fiz a instalação do módulo react-native-fbsdk, e rodei inclusive o comando react-native link, que me retornou sucesso, porém não consigo utilizar o login. A chamada "LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions" me retorna um erro em tempo de execução: "undefined is not an object".

Não sei a localização da pasta android, só vejo que a aplicação agora roda sobre a Expo. Como resolvo esse login agora?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Após alguma (longa) pesquisa, consegui resolver meu problema, então, segue aqui a solução para futuras buscas:

O Login com Facebook é fornecido pela api Expo, assim, é necessário instalá-la:

```
npm install --save expo
```

Após isso, no componente:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Text, Button } from 'native-base'
import Expo from 'expo';

export default class Component extends Component {
  render(
    <Button onPress={() => { this.facebookLogin() }}>
      <Text style={styles.btnText}>SIGN IN WITH FACEBOOK</Text>
    </Button>
  )

  async facebookLogin() {
    const ADD_ID = 'SUA_APP_ID_AQUI'
    const options = {
      permissions: ['public_profile', 'email', 'user_birthday'],
    }
    const {
      type,
      token,
    } = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(ADD_ID, options)

    if (type === 'success') {
      const baseUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`
      const fields = '&fields=email,first_name,last_name,birthday'
      const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}${fields}`)

      console.log(await response.json());
      this.authenticate(token);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente a Api Expo é nova, e ainda não tem uma boa documentação. Assim, na dúvida, leia os fontes!